# Connect Android to MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql

So I'm really new to this. 
I modified the code of new project in Android Studio to work on HTML5 with webview class, I have created a database with phpmyadmin and I created a search engine php to retrieve data from the database. 
My project is really about connecting the android application with the database, which contains a list of products like catalog, at the end it must be able to retrieve each record individually and allow user feedback. With all that I've gotten to the point that I do not know how I can connect android application with the database using all the php code that I created earlier as a seeker (with modifications or something). As I said, I'm new to all this so I do not know if use the webview to bring the search application created with php can be considered correct in android application project, important factor in the case of a school project.

Thank you very much for any comments or help that you can offer.

EDIT*
Now I have this:

```
<?php 

$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "XXX";
$bd = "XXX";


$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass,$bd) 
or die("Ha sucedido un error inexperado en la conexion de la base de datos");


$input=$_REQUEST['input'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM registres where id=".$input;
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8"); //formato de datos utf8

if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) die();

$registres = array(); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    $id=$row['id'];
    $isbn=$row['ISBN'];
    $titol=$row['titol'];
    $autor=$row['autor'];
    $any=$row['any'];
    $descripcio=$row['descripcio'];
    $format=$row['format'];

    $registres[] = array('id'=> $id, 'ISBN'=> $isbn, 'titol'=> $titol, 'autor'=> $autor, 'any'=> $any, 'descripcio'=> $descripcio, 'format'=> $format);

}

//desconectamos la base de datos
$close = mysqli_close($conexion) 
or die("Ha sucedido un error inexperado en la desconexion de la base de datos");


$json_string = json_encode($registres);
echo $json_string;



?>
```

But but the system returns the following:

Notice: Undefined index: input in E:\xampp\htdocs\json4\api\api3.php on line 13

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [android - java to phpmyadmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372812/android-java-to-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 0):

you can not run PHP code in WebView. but you can use HTML5 and Javascript. To connect database,

1. First You need to make API, for that create a page called search.php and host that to your server eg. www.yourdomain.com/search.php
2. Now code search.php to connect database and get results from mysql, store them in array and finally output as JSON

search.php

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect(host,user,pass);
$input=$_REQUEST['input'];

$sql="select * from table where field=".$input; //change table and field

$result=mysql_query($sql,$con);

$rows=array();

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $rows[]=$row;
}

echo json_encode($rows); //it outputs results as JSON
?>
```

// Now Your android Application can use AJAX call using javascript to make request to the URL, use JQUERY Mobile for easy AJAX call
www.yourdomain.com/search.php?input=some+text

and AJAX call returns JSON data that can be parsed and displayed in webview.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you don't do this. Sqlite is the recommendation of database from Android. So don't try to use other databases. All the others are too heavy for Android.

Comment: I have understood that sqlite works without internet connection. How could with sqlite allow users interacted with comments, and ratings (star rating) be visible to others? Thank You.

Comment: You need to connect to server where you use MySQL or Oracle.  Comments or ratings stored locally is not secure. You need a server to help you to achieve this.

Comment: So I supose that I should sync SQLite on Android to my MySQL, right? Comments and ratings are locally stored because it's only a university project, so no problem with this fact.

Comment: College project? You can create a server by using Tomcat. Then the client and the server are in your control. The connection will be at ease if you do so. OK, this's my advise.